# Getting SuperSearch and GWCode to play together nicely

Tags: parse-order, supersearch, gwcode-categories

Using [Solspace SuperSearch](http://www.solspace.com/docs/super_search/) I want to search by category (and keyword), and have the categories list on the result page remember which checkboxes I selected.

It works great when I am looping through the channel entries tag like so:

```
{exp:channel:categories parent_only="yes"}
{exp:super_search:variables}
    <li>
        {category_name}
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            value="{category_url_title}"
            name="category[]"
            {if super_search_category_{category_url_title}} checked="checked"{/if} />
    </li>
{/exp:super_search:variables}
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

I would like to use [GWCcode Categories](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories/documentation) to have greater control however. When I do, I run into parse order issues and the `checked="checked"` does not render:

```
{exp:gwcode_categories depth="0" max_depth="1" style="linear"}
{exp:super_search:variables}
    <li>
        {cat_name}
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            value="{cat_url_title}"
            name="category[]"
            {if super_search_category_{cat_url_title}} checked="checked"{/if} />
    </li>
{/exp:super_search:variables}
{/exp:gwcode_categories}
```

Has anyone had the same problem and gotten these two addons to work together? Any alternative methods come to mind that give me this functionality?

**EDIT:** minor syntax error in code, see comments

Comment: Have you intentionally left out the closing super search tag?

Comment: @JasonVarga no that was my mistake, I simplified my code somewhat to paste it here, accidentally removed it. The closing tag is there in my actual template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `parse="inward"` to the GWCode tag. It's a plugin tag instead of a module tag, so it will try to parse inner tags first, unless you add the `parse="inward"` parameter.

Comment: Thank you. This solved an issue where gwcode was nested inside a channel entries attempting to get children using `cat_url_title="{url_title}"`